# What subfields use computers the most and least? (soft question)

Tags: soft-question, experimental-mathematics

What areas within research mathematics use computer programming (not including $\LaTeX$) the most and least? What programming languages are most commonly used in those fields?

Comment: Theoretical Computer Science is probably among the subfields that use computers the least. (I am considering TCS as either a subfield of or a field with a huge intersection with mathematics. If only for the sake of the irony of this answer)

Comment: Another question being -- is paper writing (e.g. with $\LaTeX$) considered as "using a computer"?

Comment: I did not intend that to be counted (although I suppose it wouldn't matter for the rankings, as all field should use $\LaTeX$ equally).

Comment: I would guess that algebraic topologists don't use computers much(aside from $\LaTeX$)

Comment: My work in combinatorics often needs some programming to deal with all but the simplest data collection -- perhaps you've heard of [combinatorial explosion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)? Right now I'm starting to look at a family of ${n \choose 2}$-dimensional polytopes. After the $3$-simplex, I can't even draw the things and it takes me an hour or so to find all the vertices by hand! Hopefully with data some patterns will emerge, but I'm definitely going to be sitting down with [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) to move forward.

Comment: @SeanEnglish, funnily enough, https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~sergerar/Papers/fKenzo.pdf.

Comment: as in combinatorics, in number theory all the formulas/results except the simplest need to be tested on a computer, and the programs become  quite complicated when $N >\! > 2^{32}$

Comment: Already asked at MathOverflow :http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11084/what-programming-languages-do-mathematicians-use.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla The MathOverflow question asks which programming languages are used, this is mainly about which fields use the most programming.

Comment: Presumably you mean "use computers for computing", rather than "use computers for documentation".

Comment: The subfield (or maybe superfield) of Formal Logic uses computers a lot.  So much so that I would discourage anyone from learning logic from an instructor that hasn't written their ideas into a computer program.

Comment: @SeanEnglish: Unless said algebraic topologists are involved in some form of computational topology?

Comment: @JW You may be right. The Algebraic Topologists I know use computers solely for $\LaTeX$. I cannot speak of the entire Alg. Top. community.

Answer (score 1):

More: numerical analysis, cryptography. Less: set theory, general topology.

FORTRAN keeps being used for number crunching with C/C++ growing in popularity. Mathematica/Maple/Matlab are used almost everywhere and you will see Python, Perl, Ruby, Haskell, LISP...

Comment: Crypto maybe, but not theoretical crypto? I now very few people that actually implement, say, Indistinguishability Obfuscation primitives or FHE cryptosystems. There are, but not many... As for the languages, Julia seems to gain speed.